# Difference between "52" and 52?

Tags: perl

Guys perl is not as easy i thought its so confusing thing.I just moved to operators and I wrote some codes but I am unable to figure it out how the compiler treating them.

```
$in = "42" ;

$out = "56"+32+"good";

print $out,;
```

The output for above code is 88 and where does the good gone? and Now lets see the other one.

```
$in ="42";

$out="good52"+32;

print $out ;
```

and for these the output is 32. The question is where does the good gone that we just stored in $out and the value 52 between the " "why the compiler just printing the value as 32 but not that remaining text.And the other question is

```
$in=52;

$in="52";
```

both doing the same work "52" not working as a text . becuase when we add "52"+32 it gives as 84. what is happening and

```
$in = "hello";

$in = hello;
```

both do the same work ? or do they differ but if i print then give the same output.Its just eating up my brain.Its so confusing becuase when "52" or 52 and "hello" or hello doing the same job why did they introduce " ".I just need the explaination why its happening for above codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

At the top of your script, you would get warnings such as:

```
Argument "good" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ...
Argument "good52" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ...
```

Perl automatically reassigns a string value to numeric, if possible. So "42" + 10 actually becomes 52. But it cannot do that with a proper string value, such as "good".

Comment: cool your right TLP so what are the other use i mean use .... what more you have in it?

Comment: @cody I'm not sure exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: sorry i mean what are the other things i need to include at top my script as you said use warnings right could you tell me some more ?

Comment: @cody Those are the only two generic pragmas to use, IMO. `strict` will prevent you from making subtle mistakes, and force you to use better programming practices. `warnings` will give you more information about what really happens in your code, which will make debugging *much* easier.

Comment: @cody: `use autodie` is another.  Probably also `use v5.12` or whatever you’re using.  Possibly also `use utf8`.

Comment: `use diagnostics` is helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

In Perl, `+` is a numeric operator. It tries to interpret its two operands as numbers. `51` is the number 51. `"51"` is a string containing two digits, and the `+` operator tries to convert the string to a number, which is 51, and uses it in the calculation. `"hello"` is a string containing five letters, and when the `+` operator tries to interpret that as a number, it equates to 0 (zero).

Your first example is thus:

```
$out = "56"+32+"good";
```

which is evaluates just like:

```
$out = 56 + 32 + 0;
```

Your `print` then converts that to a string on output, and yields 88.

In perl, the `+` operator will treat its arguments as numbers, and try to convert anything that is not a number to a number. The `.` (dot) operator is used to join strings: it will try to convert its operands to strings if they aren't already strings.

Comment: how your saying "52" value is 52 and "hello" value equals zero? is there any method to do it?

Comment: Perl tries to convert the string ("52" or "hello") to a number.  If that fails, then it uses the default value zero ("52" --> 52, "hello" --> 0).

Comment: @cody: The method to it is simple - if the string begins with numeric characters (digits/decimal point/leading `-`), that's the numeric value. If it begins with anything else, the numeric value is 0. So "-4.2bravo" has a numeric value of -4.2, while "bravo-4.2" has a numeric value of 0 (because it starts with "b", which is non-numeric).

Answer (score 2):

In perl, a string in a numerical context (like when you use a `+` operator) is converted to a number.

In perl, you can concatenate string using the `.` (dot) operator, not `+`.

If you use `+`, perl will try and interpret all of the operands as numbers. This works well for strings that are number representations, otherwise you get 0. This explains what you see.

> `$in=52;`
>
> `$in="52";`
>
> both doing the same work "52" not working as a text . becuase when we add "52"+32 it gives as 84.

The problem here is not with the variable definition. One is a string and the other a number. But when you use the string in a numerical expression (`+`), then it will converted to number.

About your second question:

1. `$in = "hello"` defines a string, as you expect;
2. `$in = hello;` will just copy the symbol hello (however it is defined) on to your variable. This is actually not "strict" perl and if you set `use strict;` in your file, perl will complain about it.

Comment: but sergio check out these thing difference between "52" and 52 answer that buddy

Comment: I dont want to concatenate or something sergio. I just started today itself I'm checking the thing how they work anyways thanks for letting me know the . operator for concatenation.But now i want you to answer that question please

Comment: see my edit. as far as i understand the question is answered: a string in a numerical context is converted to a number.

Answer (score 1):

First off, give [this](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlstringnum.htm) a read.

Your problem is that the `+` is a mathematical addition, which doesn't work on strings.  If you use that, Perl will assume that you're working with numbers and therefore discard anything that isn't.

To concatenate strings, use `.`:

```
$str = "blah " . "blah " . "blah";
```

As far as the difference between `"52"` and `52` goes, there isn't one.  Since nothing (commands, comments, etc.) in Perl can start with numbers, the compiler doesn't need the quotes to know what to do.

Comment: Guys i understood but tell me the difference between "52" and 52 why does it add if i say "52"+32 and also 52+32 whats the use of " " this then

Comment: Underneath the hood there is a difference between `$foo="52";` and `$foo=52;`. Perl variables can have a string representation, an integer representation, a numeric (floating point) representation, and other magical stuff. With the right magic, a perl variable can, for example, be made to have a numeric value of 1 but a string value of 'Operation not permitted',  a numeric value of 2 but a string value of 'No such file or directory', and so on.

Comment: That's interesting.  I knew about the different representations, but I didn't know that you could manipulate them like that.  I always just assumed that they were all just the various typed forms of the same base value, and that the compiler simply used the appropriate one for whatever it had to do.  Now that you mention it though it does make sense that you could play with them like that.  Thanks for the tip!